# How is it possible that gnome-software can install applications in arch without root access?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, package-management

I don't have much experience with arch, but in Ubuntu you always needed root, and with pacman -S you need it as well, but if I use gnome-software then it installs without any problems! How is this possible?

Comment: I just installed `gnome-software` from the repos and it asks for root password when I try to install something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a component called [Polkit](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/polkit/) that is used by many applications to request root permissions to do things (it can do so because it's a daemon running as root). Polkit can be configured to ask for a password (either your user account password or the root password) or to just allow it without a password prompt. That decision can be based on any number of things (e.g., mounting a removable drive requires root access—Polkit is often configured to allow the person sitting in front of the computer to do that without a password, but someone ssh'ing in to the computer gets asked for a password).

Most likely, Arch is just using different Polkit settings than Ubuntu does.